# On reputation values

Tags: support, reputation

Why some `upvote` gives me `+5` and others `+10`? What is the rule here?

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation Votes for questions are +5, votes for answers are +10.

Comment: Ow, sorry. Too easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: For detailed instruction on this, see [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/168244)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Positive) Votes for questions give +5 in reputation while votes on answers are worth +10: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation for the full detail.